# Interpretable Measure of Association between a dichotomous variable and a variable with more than two ordered categories

Tags: categorical-data, association-measure

What measure of association including a positive or negative sign can be used to evaluate the association between a dichotomous variable (i.e. YES, NO) and a categorical ordinal variable (ie. A lot, moderate, little bit)?

Comment: Not really interpretable (except for the fact that it is zero if they are independent): There is at least one measure that is being used regularly in decision trees: MI (mutual information, see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)

Comment: Any rank-based correlation (Spearman, Kendall) will do.